# Is there a way to use the 256-bit integer type in ink?

Tags: ink, rust

In the ink! documentation I found the Keccak256 hash, which gives back a 256-bit hash.
However I can not find a 256-bit integer in the ink! documentation.
If I want to cast from the 32 bytes to an integer value, how could I do
so in the ink! environment?

Comment: Can you describe what you're trying to do?

There's no natural mapping between a hash (or a series on bytes) an integer, so how you get from one to the other depends on what your goal is.

Comment: Solidity has the datatype uint256 and bytes32. Since uint256 has the same size as bytes32, a cast between the two does not seem complicated (and is also possible). I want to do a similar thing in rust. I want to write a smart contract using ink! which uses the Keccak2456 hash which returns [u8; 32]. I want to cast those in an integer value, however only a uint256 would be big enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rust doesn't have a u256 in its standard library and neither does ink!. However, you can use crates that provide this type.

For example, the [`ethnum`](https://crates.io/crates/ethnum) crate:

```rust
use ethnum::U256;

fn main() {
  let bytes: [u8; 32] = [0; 32];
  let _: U256 = U256::from_le_bytes(bytes);
}
```

The method [`from_le_bytes`](https://docs.rs/ethnum/1.2.2/ethnum/struct.U256.html#method.from_le_bytes) here takes bytes in little-endian, there's also a method for big-endian.